# Why is 得 put before 我 in 搬家公司只管大件，小东西还得我亲自动手?

Tags: grammar

In the following conversation:

> A: 小湖，这几天你怎么没来下棋呀？
>
> B: 为了搬家我忙得焦头烂额。哪儿有时间下棋呀？
>
> A: 你可以委托搬家公司呀？
>
> B: 搬家公司只管大件，小东西还**得**我亲自动手。

I'm sure the 得 here means "have to ~" or "must" (so it is `dei`, not `de`). However, the subject is likely 我, not 小东西.

So why is place of 得 not after 我 in this sentence? Is it OK and if that is the case, how can I know in what case should I put 得 before the subject?

Comment: Just think about Modal verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it OK and if that is the case, how can I know in what case should I put 得 before the subject?

This is OK. You can change the order of words for the purpose of emphasis; note that the object being emphasized changes according to the position of 得. e.g.

> 我还得亲自动手（搬）小东西。
>
> 小东西我还得亲自动手（搬）。 => for emphasizing the object, i.e. 小东西
>
> 小东西还得我亲自动手（搬）。 => not only emphasizes the object but also the subject, i.e. 我

BTW 得 is not the verb; as you said it means "need", "have to" or "must", the verb is 搬 which is omitted. This is a kind of 宾语前置 (object fronting), i.e. change from S-V-O structure to O-S-V structure.

Comment: Thanks but even in these cases I usually see the sentence keeps S + V + O structure, IIRC. So I wonder why this sentence puts V before S...

Comment: @Blaszard Answer revised.

Comment: Thanks and that makes sense! Are these types of inversion common in Chinese as well?

Comment: @Blaszard Yes, that's why there's a special term "宾语前置" for it. For this case "得" has involvement then makes it a little complex.

Answer (score 0):

> 搬家公司只管大件，小东西还得我亲自动手。
>
> 搬家公司只管大件，小东西我还得亲自动手。

These two sentences mean the same. If you don't understand the grammar of the first one, you can think about this sentence:

> 小东西(*他们*)还得 **让** 我亲自动手。

Where 我 is the indirect object of 让 and virtual subject 他们 could be 搬家公司. So, the whole translation can be *"For those things small, (they) have to let me to handle"*.

Comment: This seems to be quite different answer from the one by @songyuanyao♦...

Comment: @Blaszard, just another way to explain it. The goal is to help you to understand. Sometimes, a Chinese sentence can be understood in a few different ways from the grammar standpoint, but the meaning will remain the same. The way I show you for this sentence is based on the way you usually comprehend. Songyuanyao's answer is correct too, but it seems that you were quite struggling with that.